# jQuery .css doesn't respond to loaded ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

With all my ajax loads: the main page responds to all jQuery.css directions, but not any of the loaded ajax. Fogive this simplistic example to help make my point. It's the concept I don't understand.
When I load (1), the (1.a) image responds to the jquery .css in (2.b).
When I click (1.b), (3) is called which loads (4).
However, the (4.b) images do not respond to (2.b).

```
In (4a), I've tried:
<body onload='ImgCss()'/>
and/or <html><head><script type='text/javascript'>ImgCss()</script></head>
and/or <html><head><script type='text/javascript'> ($document).ect. </script></head>
```

I understand one can use .live with events. Is there an equal with .css? If not, what am I missing?
I'm not interested in *<style type="text/css"></style>* unless there's no other way.

```
(1)<html><head>
<meta name="language" content="English">
<title>Clowns</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jsClowns.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload='ImgCss()'>
<table id='tblMainMenu' width="100%"> <!-- begin master table -->
    <tr><td>
    (1.a)<img class='ClownImage' src='clownDir/InitClown.gif' 
    (1.b)onClick='jsShowAllClowns("jaxClowns.php","jaxContainer")' />
    </td></tr>
<tr><td id="jaxContainer"></td>
</table>
```

```
    (2) jsClowns.js
    (2.a) function jsShowAllClowns(jaxURL, jaxContainer) {
    $.get( jaxURL,
    function(data) { $('#'+ jaxContainer).html(data); } 
    ); 
}
    (2.b) function ImgCSS(){$("img.ClownImage").css({'width':'205px','height':'205px'});}

(3) jaxClowns.php <?php
    include_once( "ClownList.php" ); ?>

(4) ClownList.php 
    (4.a)<html><head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="app_modules/class/javascript/jsClowns.js"></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table><tr>
          <?php
          $aList = GetClownList();
          for($i=0; $i<count($aList); $i++):
              $img=$aList[$i];  
              (4.b)echo "<td><img  class='ClownImage' src="$Img" ?><br /></td>";
          nextfor;   ?>
        </tr></table>
    </body></htm>
```

Comment: Is my answer was helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but probably it's a solution:

move this code:

```
$("img.ClownImage").css({'width':'205px','height':'205px'});
```

to:

```
$.get( jaxURL, function(data) {
    $('#'+ jaxContainer).html(data);
    //here
});
```

It should cause that style will be assigned to elements after with `get` success callbak.

---

Another way. Why don't you just put css code into your **css file**?

```
img.ClownImage{
    width:205px;
    height:205px'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after you click 1.b and 4 is loaded in the container #jaxContainer

you need to call 2.b again so that this function(2.b) is called again on the recent elements added by calling 2.a

so change the 2.a to

```
function jsShowAllClowns(jaxURL, jaxContainer) {
    $.get( jaxURL,
    function(data) { $('#'+ jaxContainer).html(data); 
    ImgCSS()
    });
```